# Azure function read SQLite database

Tags: c#, azure, sqlite, azure-functions

From a third party I am receiving a SQLite '.db3' database file. I wish to read the data stored within the database in an Azure function, but have no requirement to modify the database.

In my Azure function I have also uploaded a text file alongside the .db3 file, I can read the contents of this text file just fine, meaning that I have the URI and read privileges on the folder.

When I try to read some data from the database I get the error 'database is locked'.

Code to read the database is below. This works locally.

```
List<object> obs = new List<object>();
using(var con = new SQLiteConnection($"URI=file:{fullUri};mode=ReadOnly"))
{
    con.Open();
    using(var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, con))
    {
        using(SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while(rdr.Read())
            {
                obs.Add(rdr.GetValues());
            }
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
return obs;
```

How do I read the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this problem before, reading a local file ... more than once. These are the steps I took depending on the scenario:

1. If your Azure Function is deployed using zipdeploy then under the "Configuration" > "Application Settings", change "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE" from `1` to `0`.
2. If the file you are trying to reference is saved under `wwwroot` on the Azure Function I would try put it somewhere else e.g. `d:\local`.

Comment: Copying the file to d:\local allowed me to access it. Thanks!